# Understanding Creating a UIView programmatically with constraints tutorial?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm following this tutorial:
http://matthewmorey.com/creating-uiviews-programmatically-with-auto-layout/

In it (I think) he creates a little red subview and adds constraints to the red subview.

But don't you need to add constraints to the view itself (the green part)?

Lets say you wanted to make the green view always be full screen as the image shows in his tutorial.  How would you do that?

Comment: The green view will always take the full screen as he has passed to self.view.self.view has default frame to take up the entire view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The green background will automatically fill an `MDMView`, whatever its frame is.

This line (already in the tutorial) sets an `MDMView` to be the `view` of an `MDMViewController`:

```
self.view = [[MDMView alloc] init];
```

And `window.rootViewController` automatically fills the window with its view:

```
MDMViewController *rootViewController = [[MDMViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
```

So, no, there is nothing more you need to do in code to get the green to fill the screen.

You will, however, need to add a Retina 4 LaunchImage asset to Images.xcassets. It should be 640 x 1136. This serves to indicate that the app should support 4-inch and larger screens. Without this asset, you'll get black bars at the top and bottom on larger screens.

Answer (score 0):

What it is saying is

```
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
self.view = contentView;
```

It means the green view is main view. You don't need to set constraints for main view. It will always be full screen.